# Call Management System

Tags: php, mysql, phone-call

I'm working on a call-management system in PHP and MySQL.

I have two tables in my database, one called students which stores the information about the people the calls need to be made to, and the other one called Calls which just records when these calls were made.

[image: Students Table]

[image: Calls Table]

Now, let's say I have two callers logging in who are supposed to make the calls. I need to show them both the different set of callers ensuring that no two logged in callers see the same 'student' for the call. Since I will be using the students table to populate my callers from, how can this be accomplished? Should I restructure my database to allow something like this.

The criteria for showing the calls that need to be dialed today would be 'uncalled users', 'users who gave a time in the last call for a specific call-time'.

The callers can also be frozen incase the guy called wants to talk to only to the guy who called him. I can detail it a bit more, if this is tough to understand. What would be the best way to go about something like this?

Comment: It sounds like you first want to assign a caller to each student, then each caller only sees the students to which they have been assigned.  Is that right?  If so, perhaps adding (and somehow populating) a `students.caller` column will suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Here's two solutions, the latter being far more complicated to impliment. Let me know if I should elaborate on either solution.

1. Upon logging in, assign a subset of the callers to the logged in user. When he's finished with a caller, and does an action to "complete" that caller, assign a new caller to the user. This way he will always have X callers assigned to him.
2. Use "long-polling" to consistently see which calls are available. So, if user A clicks on caller 1, user B will not be able to click on caller 1 until user A either stops using caller 1, or user A's sessions times out.

Let me know if I'm on the right track and I'll see how I can improve my answer.